# Заменить TextBox на TextBox с OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Изначально программа была составлена так, что пользователь вводил полностью путь до файла в TextBox. Необходимо теперь "прикрутить" OpenFileDialog, чтобы можно было выбрать .txt файл с помощью обзора файлов. Как это сделать?
Добавила еще кнопку для обзора файлов, но она не работает:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = this.PathFromUser.Text;
    path = RemoveBraces(path);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Введите путь!");
        return;
    }
    //           OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    //           if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    string filePath = path;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt";
        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

    }
    string outputfilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + FINAL_FILE_NALE;

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Неккоректный путь!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Дальше идет кнопка выполнения основной программы.

Comment: Как-то вообще не понятно. Почему сначала открываете диалог, а уже при удачном выборе файла устанавливаете фильтр, в чем логика? Что конкретно не работает? НЕ появляется выбранный файл в TextBox? Опишите, хотя бы, что вы ожидаете от этого метода